# winium with notepad "alt + f" not working in python code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, winium

Someone help me to fix hotkey combination of "alt + n" and "alt + f" after launching notepad in windows 10 with scale 100%

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    driver1 = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://localhost:2121',
        desired_capabilities={
        "debugConnectToRunningApp": 'false',
        "keyboardSimulator": '0',
        "app": r"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
        })
    combine_keys = ActionChains(driver1)
    combine_keys.key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys('f').key_up(Keys.ALT).perform()  /* used command */
```

Tried modifying capability ""keyboardSimulator" 0/1 nothing works.
I am using latest Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe and tried few combination send_keys but still no luck
TIA

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow @arunrona. You may use the backticks \`some code\` to put the code inside a box for software code, as edited above ;)

Comment: I add few more comment to the above code `combine_keys.key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys('f').key_up(Keys.ALT).perform() ` same code used ROBOT framework as `Press keys    name=<my attribute>    ALT+n` where it working as separate like first pressing 'ALT' key and released and then going for key 'n' it is not doing it in combined press. I am confused whether WINIUM supports combined key press at a time.